# Не отображается апплет в браузере

Tags: java, applet

Не отображается апплет в браузере (даже выделенного под апплет места нету, просто пустая страница), помогите, пожалуйста. Вот код апплета и html-страницы. В Eclipse апплет запускается (через средство appletviewer). Это простой калькулятор. Я в отчаянии.

```
package lesson14;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class prog extends JApplet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea text;
    private double p1=0, p2=0;
    private int oper = 0;


    private void btnClick(JButton btn) {

        String str = btn.getText();

        if(str == "Выход")
            System.exit(0);
        else if(str == "C") {
            text.setText("");
            p1=p2=0;
        }
        else if(str == "=") {
            p2 = Integer.parseInt(text.getText());
            if(oper == 1) text.setText("" + (p1+p2));
            if(oper == 2) text.setText("" + (p1-p2));
            if(oper == 3) text.setText("" + (p1*p2));
            if(oper == 4) text.setText("" + (p1/p2));
        }
        else if(str == "+") {
            oper = 1;
            p1 = Double.parseDouble(text.getText());
            text.setText("");
        }
        else if(str == "-") {
            oper = 2;
            p1 = Double.parseDouble(text.getText());
            text.setText("");
        }
        else if(str == "*") {
            oper = 3;
            p1 = Double.parseDouble(text.getText());
            text.setText("");
        }
        else if(str == "/") {
            oper = 4;
            p1 = Double.parseDouble(text.getText());
            text.setText("");
        }
        else {
            text.setText("" + text.getText() + str);
        }
    }

    public void init() {

        Container cont = getContentPane();
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        cont.add(pan);

        pan.setLayout(null);

        Font btnFont = new Font("serif", 0, 20);
        Font lblFont = new Font("arial", 1, 30);
        Font txtFont = new Font("arial", 2, 30);

        JButton[] btn = new JButton[17];

        for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
            btn[i] = new JButton();
            btn[i].setSize(100,25);
            btn[i].setFont(btnFont);
            btn[i].setLocation(30, 50 + i*30);
            btn[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    btnClick((JButton)e.getSource());
                }
            });
            pan.add(btn[i]);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            btn[i].setText("" + i);

        btn[10].setText("+");
        btn[11].setText("-");
        btn[12].setText("/");
        btn[13].setText("*");
        btn[14].setText("=");
        btn[15].setText("C");
        btn[16].setText("Выход");

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Результат");
        lbl.setFont(lblFont);
        lbl.setBounds(130, 0, 300, 50);
        pan.add(lbl);

        text = new JTextArea();
        text.setFont(txtFont);
        text.setBounds(300,10,300,35);
        text.setForeground(new Color(0,0,100));
        text.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pan.add(text);
    }
}
```

И вот код HTML-страницы

```
<html>
    <body>
        <applet archive="prog.jar" code="lesson14/prog.class" width="800" height="600" >
        </applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: в последних версиях браузеров в конфигурации по умолчанию апплеты отключены, вроде как. если вообще поддерживаются ещё...

Comment: Возьмите браузер какой-нибудь постарее.

Comment: Если у вас Chrome, то увы: https://java.com/ru/download/faq/chrome.xml, если другие: https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/browser_activate_plugin.xml

Answer (score 1):

С 2015-го года многие браузеры перестали поддерживать апплеты. С сентября 2017 Oracle объявили технологию устаревшей. Скорее всего, в 2018-м её окончательно уберут из Java.